# Querying association table object directly

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have to query the relationships directly, since I have to display them seperatly.

```
task_user = db.Table(
    'pimpy_task_user',
    db.Column('task_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pimpy_task.id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)
```

How do I do this in SQLAlchemy?
When I try this:

```
tasks_rel = task_user.join(Task).join(User).filter(Task.group_id == group_id)
```

It causes this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Join' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the usage you have above is creating a [join()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.join) construct, which is a Core (non-ORM) construct representing a join() of two tables (but not a full blown select()).

when using the ORM you usually start off a SELECT using the Query object.   Querying from the class itself is a pattern offered by extensions like flask-sqlalchemy, but these extensions are usually confusing in this regard.   Given any class or table you can query against it using the Query object:

```
session.query(task_user).join(Task).join(User).filter(Task.group_id == group_id)
```